# Regex Lookahead/Lookbehind if more than one occurance

Tags: regex, google-docs, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have string formulas like this:

```
?{a,b,c,d}
```

It can be can be embedded like this:

```
?{a,b,c,?{x,y,z}}
```

or this is the same:

```
?{a,b,c,
    ?{x,y,z}
}
```

So I have to find those commas, what are in the second and greather "level" brackets.
In the example below I marked the "levels" where I have to find all commas:

```
?{a,b,c,
    ?{x,y,          <--Those
        ?{1,2,3}    <--Those
    }
}
```

I've tried with lookahead and lookbehind, but I'm totally confused now :/

Here is my latest working try, but it is not good at all:
[OnlineRegex](https://regex101.com/r/KQB59r/2)

**Update:**
To avoid misunderstanding, I don't want to count the commas.
I'd like to get groups of commas to replace them.

The condition is find the commas where more than one "open tags" before it like this: ?{

.. without closing tag like this: }

Examlpe.:
In this case I have not replace any commas:

```
?{1,2,3} ?{a,b,c}
```

But in this case I have to replace commas between a b c

```
?{1,2,3,?{a,b,c}}
```

Comment: What makes you think that a regex is the good tool here?

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Comment: The formulas in an excel spreadsheet, and I have to change this commas to an other character.
I would like to do it in this spreadsheet with Excel formulas only, and I found this: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245

Comment: Vadim: this is an extract only, it is a special macro coding (roll20.net)

Comment: What do you need to extract?

Comment: revo: I mean the samples I have written are simplified formulas, but they are useful to try with regex.

Comment: Here is my latest try: https://regex101.com/r/KQB59r/4
The problem is only find the first commas in the brackets

Comment: @norbre [`(?<!^\?{[^{}]*),`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5e%5c%3f%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%29%2c&i=%3f%7ba%2cb%2cc%2c%0d%0a++++%3f%7bx%2cy%2c++++++++++%0d%0a++++++++%3f%7b1%2c2%2c3%7d+++%0d%0a++++%7d%0d%0a%7d) works for all the examples provided by you except the second last example. Also, I have used .Net RegEx as it provides a bit more support for the lookbehinds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the examples which you have provided, the following regex works(gives the desired output as mentioned by you):

```
(?<!^\?{[^{}]*),(?=[\s\S]*(?:\s*}){2,})
```

---

For String `?{a,b,c,d}`, see **[Demo1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5E%5C%3F%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D*%29%2C%28%3F%3D%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%28%3F%3A%5Cs*%7D%29%7B2%2C%7D%29&i=%3F%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%2Cd%7D) No Match**

---

For String, `?{a,b,c,?{x,y,z}}`, see **[Demo2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5E%5C%3F%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D*%29%2C%28%3F%3D%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%28%3F%3A%5Cs*%7D%29%7B2%2C%7D%29&i=%3F%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%2C%3F%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%7D) Match successful**

---

For String,

```
?{a,b,c,
    ?{x,y,z}
}
```

see **[Demo3](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5E%5C%3F%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D*%29%2C%28%3F%3D%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%28%3F%3A%5Cs*%7D%29%7B2%2C%7D%29&i=%3F%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%0D%0A%7D) Match Successful**

---

For String,

```
?{a,b,c,
    ?{x,y,          
        ?{1,2,3}   
    }
}
```

see **[Demo4](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5E%5C%3F%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D*%29%2C%28%3F%3D%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%28%3F%3A%5Cs*%7D%29%7B2%2C%7D%29&i=%3F%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%7Bx%2Cy%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) Match Successful**

---

For String `?{1,2,3} ?{a,b,c} ?{1,2,3} ?{a,b,c}`, see **[Demo5](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5E%5C%3F%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D*%29%2C%28%3F%3D%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%28%3F%3A%5Cs*%7D%29%7B2%2C%7D%29&i=%3F%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%20%3F%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D%20%3F%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%20%3F%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D) No Match**

---

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!^\?{[^{}]*),` - negative lookbehind to discard the 1st level commas. The logic applied here is it should not match the comma which is preceded by start of the string followed by `?{` followed by 0+ occurrences of any character except `{` or `}`
- `(?=[\s\S]*(?:\s*}){2,})` - The comma matched above must be followed by **atleast** 2 occurrences of `}`(consecutive or having only whitespaces between them)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you the help andthe detailed explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear @norbre, but I presume you'd like to extract (i.e. "count") the number of commas.
You can't do this with a regex. Regexps can't count number of occurences. However, you can use this to extract the "internal part" and then use a spreadsheet formula to count number of commas:

`^(?:\?{[a-zA-Z0-9,]+?,\n??\s*?\?{)([a-zA-Z0-9,?{}\n\s]+?(?:\n*?\s*?|})+)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9,\n\s]*})$`

Try: https://regex101.com/r/Rr0eFo/5

---

**Examples**

1.
Input:

```
?{a,b,c,?{e,f},1,2,3}
```

Output:

```
e,f}
```

2.
Input:

```
?{a,b,c,  
    ?{x,y,z,e,  
        ?{1,2,3,?{f,g,3},4,5,6}  
}  
,d,e,f}
```

Output:

```
x,y,z,e,
        ?{1,2,3,?{f,g,3},4,5,6}
}
```

3.
Input:

```
?{a,b,c,?{e},1,2,3}
```

Output:

```
e}
```

*(note that there are no commas here!)*

---

**One caveat however.** As I have said, regexps can't count number of occurences.
Hence, the following sample (don't know if it's valid or not for your case) would return wrong match:

```
?{a,b,c,?{e,f}
    ,1,2,3,?{a,b}
}
```

Output:

```
e,f}
    ,1,2,3,?{a,b}
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear.. I Don't want to count commas.
I have to replace all of the commas in the lines I've marked, or in other words with regexp I'd like to get groups of those commas.

I update my first comment..

Answer (score 0):

OK replacing commas is another story so I'll add another answer.
Your regexp engine would need to support recursion.

Still I don't see a way to do it with one regex - one match would either contain the first comma or contain everything between the braces!

What I suggest is to use one regexp to get "what is inside the inner braces", run a replace `(, => "")` and assemble the whole line again using submatches from the regexp.

Here it is: `(\?{[^?{}]*)((?>[^?{}]|(?R))+?)([^?{}]*?\})`

Try: https://regex101.com/r/IzTeY0/3

Example 1:
Input:

```
?{a,b,c,
    ?{x,y,z,e,
        ?{1,2,3,?{f,g,3},4,5,6}
}

,d,e,f}
```

Submatches:
1. `?{a,b,c,`
2. `?{x,y,z,e,
        ?{1,2,3,?{f,g,3},4,5,6}
}`
3. 
`,d,e,f}`

Replace all commas in submatch 2 with anything you want, then reassamble the whole string using submatches 1 and 3.

---

**Again, this would break the regexp:**

```
?{a,b,c,?{e,f}
    ,1,2,3,?{a,b}
}
```

Submatch 2 would look like this:

```
 ?{e,f}
    ,1,2,3,?{a,b}
```